# What is the reason to getting like this error's "No mapping for GET"?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

i'm getting errors while execution in spring MVC, but in my code i'm not able to fine.I'm trying to solve this problem. But i'm not getting where i  had did wrong.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController 
{
   @RequestMapping("login")
   public void loginController()
   {
    System.out.println("login method is called");
    return login.jsp;
   }

   @RequestMapping("register")
   public void registerController()
   {
        return register.jsp;
   }
}


<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hospital</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>    
     <servlet-name>hospital</servlet-name>    
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kauvery"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Can you show us the errors please ?

Comment: check the URI and method type in controller better share the hitting URL and controller code

Comment: Is your code compiling? you have controller methods as void and its returning jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

1.add this bean definition into the servlet.xml file

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

2.all jsp files put into "/WEB-INF/jsp" path

3.void is not a return type. so change the return type of methods in controller as String

4.add slash ("/") to the url pattern

5.return types of methods in the controller are String. hence every method return the view name (related jsp file name) as String value.

6.reomove the file extension of the jsp file (view) name. because above bean definition tell to the spring these files name extension is a ".jsp" (`<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />`) and these files are located in "/WEB-INF/jsp" (`<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />`) path

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String loginController(){
    System.out.println("login method is called");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/register")
public String registerController(){
    return "register";
}
```